# How to invoke a plugin from Jenkins build pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have pipeline job in my Jenkins 2.x installation. In one of my steps I want to invoke a third party plugin that hasn't been updated to support pipeline jobs.

How can I invoke that plugin and have it run from my pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use snippet generator and look for `step` there, and you will see a list of plugins.
[image]

It works for some plugins only, so if yours is not there you are out of luck.

Comment: I ended up switching to the xUnit plugin, which is supported by the Snippet generator.